# Why context.getUser().getMail() returns null?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

it works on one server but doesn't work if I open xPage from another server.
What should I tune up on Domino or maybe in db ACL?
Not sure If I can get current user mail address through the session object.

Comment: Are you logged in on "another" server with your name/password or do you access it with Anonymous? The latter would be the reason for the issue...

Comment: I'm logged in with name/password through Domino login page. And it works on another Domino with same xPages db app. But not on the new Domino where we moved this db.

Comment: Do you have the same Domino Directory (with the user document) on this new server too?

Comment: Well, I have no idea actually. What I really need to check?

Comment: Look at database names.nsf on servers and check for your person document. Is it the same?

Comment: I don't have my personal record in names.nsf of that server as well as on the server where context.getUser() works